# Filemaker - Adding a button to infoWindow in GoogleMaps API v3 via web viewer to change layout

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, filemaker

I have looked far and wide for an answer to this question but I am stuck. What I want to do is have a map populate into a Webviewer using Google Maps API v3.

I have populated with a marker and on clicking the marker, an infoWindow is displayed. Within the infoWindow, is a button that will be used (hopefully) to accomplish my goal.

At this point, I am unable to get anything from the button at all. I have tried using responses to the questions similar to this one but I have had no luck. I also need to know if I can navigate through the layouts directly from the web viewer and back again.

i.e. I would like a map to display, populated with markers of all clients within a 10 KM radius. I would then like the infoWindow to display client info such as name address and other relevant info. All this I can do (mostly) however, what I need to accomplish is a button or link within that info window that when clicked will navigate to another layout within filemaker to display that clients record.

Can this actually be achieved? and if so, how would I do this?

I have included the current version of the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=USING VALID API KEY HERE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397,150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Tony McShane</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>TONY</b>, also referred to as <b>Epic Douchebag</b>, is a dude from cranny' +
      '</p>'+
      '<div id="button_div" style="text-align:centre">'+
      '<button id="myBtn" onclick="<a href=FMP://www.myURLhere.com/iCOMPLI%20Auditor%20_Tenancy%20Lite%20Metcash%20upgrade.fmp12?script=goto_iCompli%20Map%20Info%20Window%20Button%20Click%20TEST type="button">Click Me!</button>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString

  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Tony McShane, You Have Failed This Database'
  });
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

}

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(myBtn, 'click', function() {

        alert("THIS WORKED");
      });
    });


    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is well supported. The piece you're missing is [the fmp:// protocol](http://help.filemaker.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5560/~/opening-shared-databases-remotely-using-a-url), which acts as a bridge between the web viewer and native FileMaker. This enables calling FileMaker scripts directly from your JavaScript code.

In your JavaScript (wherever you want to call a FileMaker script), you set the web viewer's location property to a valid fmp url. The fmp protocol lets you specify which script to invoke and parameter passing. Once validly set up, this works very well. Here's a [detailed overview of how to set this up](https://blog.beezwax.net/2012/04/21/native-web-2-0-controls-in-filemaker-12-layouts/).